# How can prove $\frac{x_n}{n}+\frac{ x_{n-1}}{n-1}+...+\frac{x_3}{3}+\frac{y_m}{m}+\frac{ y_{m-1}}{m-1}+...+\frac{y_3}{3} \ge 1$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, diophantine-equations

Let $A, a, b$ be positive integer numbers, $gcd(a,b)=1; a\ne b$ and

$A=x_na^n+x_{n-1}a^{n-1}+....+x_3a^3
=y_mb^m+y_{m-1}b^{m-1}+....+y_3b^3$

Where $x_i \in 0, 1, 2,..., a$ and $y_j \in 0, 1, 2,..., b$, and $n, m \ge 3$, $x_n \ne 0$, $y_m \ne 0 $

> How can prove that:
>
> $$\frac{x_n}{n}+\frac{ x_{n-1}}{n-1}+...+\frac{x_3}{3}+\frac{y_m}{m}+\frac{ y_{m-1}}{m-1}+...+\frac{y_3}{3} \ge 1$$

Can you help me?

**See also:**

- [Hexadecima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)
- [Decima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal)

Comment: yes, Ok. You are right, I corrected

Comment: What about my counter-example?

Comment: @MartinR Because $n, m >2$, I mean max level of $a, b > 2$

Comment: @MartinR or I should put detail condition that $x_n \ne 0$ and $y_m \ne 0 $

Comment: If $a < b$ and $b^3 \leqslant A < 2a^3$, then your sum is $\frac{x_3}{3} + \frac{y_3}{3} = \frac{2}{3} < 1$.

Comment: May you make detail Dear @DanielFischer ?

Comment: Take for example $a = 4,\, b = 5,\, A = 127$.

Comment: @DanielFischer can I edited one time to same original at here?

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u192421h1471305p8538256